# Web scraping multiple levels of a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am looking to scrape a website. Then, for each scraped item I want to scrape further info on sub web pages. As an example I'll use the IMDB website. I am using the `rvest` package and the [selector gadget](http://selectorgadget.com) in Google chrome.

From the IMDB site I can get the [top 250 rated TV shows](http://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/?ref_=nv_tp_tv250_2) as follows:

```
library('rvest')

# url to be scrapped
url <- 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/?ref_=nv_tp_tv250_2'

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

#Using CSS selectors to scrap
movies_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.titleColumn a')

#Converting the TV show data to text
movies <- html_text(movies_html)

head(movies)
[1] "Planet Earth II"  "Band of Brothers" "Planet Earth"     "Game of Thrones"  "Breaking Bad"     "The Wire"
```

Each of the top 250 movies in the list is a clickable link that gives additional info on each of the movies. In this case for each movie in `movies` I would like to also scrape the cast and store this in another `list`. For example if you click on the second to top movie "Band of brothers" and scroll down the cast consists of ~40 people from Scott Grimes to Phil McKee.

Pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
for(i in movies) {
  url <- 'http://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/i'
  webpage <- read_html(url)
  cast_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'#titleCast .itemprop')
  castList<- html_text(cast_html)
}
```

I am sure this is very simple but it is new to me and I don't know how to search for the right terms to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to find a way to

1. Identify the URLs to the movie pages from the top 250 (`main_url`)
2. Get the titles of the top 250 shows (`m_titles`)
3. Visit those URLs (`m_urls`)
4. Extract the cast of those TV shows (`m_cast`)

Correct?

We'll start off by defining a function that extracts the cast from a TV Show page:

```
getcast <- function(url){
  page <- read_html(url)
  nodes <- html_nodes(page, '#titleCast .itemprop')
  cast <- html_text(nodes)

  inds <- seq(from=2, to=length(cast), by=2)
  cast <- cast[inds]
  return(cast)
}
```

With that in place, we can work down points 1 through 4:

```
# Open main_url and navigate to interesting part of the page:
main_url <- "http://www.imdb.com/chart/toptv/?ref_=nv_tp_tv250_2"

main_page <- read_html(url)
movies_html <- html_nodes(main_page, '.titleColumn a')

# From the interesting part, get the titles and URLs:
m_titles <- html_text(movies_html)

sub_urls <- html_attr(movies_html, 'href')
m_urls <- paste0('http://www.imdb.com', sub_urls)

# Use `getcast()` to extract movie cast from every URL in `m_urls`
m_cast <- lapply(m_urls, getcast)
```

Comment: There is a small error, `read_html(url)` should be `read_html(main_url)`, SO wouldn't let me edit your  post for a fix of less than 6 characters. But yes this is exactly what I wanted, thank you!